# <div> elements are appearing out of order

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I have an "form-inline" with a label and two div. The problem is that the second div is appearing before the first div:

[image]

```
    .fullWidth {
        width: 100% !important
    }

        <form class= "form-inline" role="form" id="showTestForm">
            <div class="container-fluid col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 bg-success">
                <div class="blueBorder container-fluid col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
                    <div class="form-group container-fluid col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                        <label class="control-label control-label-left col-lg-2 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12" for="addFromDate">From:</label>

                        <div class="input-group date text-left col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-12 col-xs-12" id="datepicker1">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="addFromDate" name="addFromDate" placeholder="DD/MM/YYYY">
                            <span class="input-group-addon">
                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                            </span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="text-right col-lg-3 col-md-2 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                            <input class="fullWidth" type="text" id="addFromTime" name="addFromTime" placeholder="24 Hr">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you have any other JS or CSS going on? It seems to be working as expected.

```html
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">


<form class= "form-inline" role="form" id="showTestForm">
            <div class="container-fluid col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 bg-success">
                <div class="blueBorder container-fluid col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
                    <div class="form-group container-fluid col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                        <label class="control-label control-label-left col-lg-2 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12" for="addFromDate">From:</label>

                        <div class="input-group date text-left col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-12 col-xs-12" id="datepicker1">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="addFromDate" name="addFromDate" placeholder="DD/MM/YYYY">
                            <span class="input-group-addon">
                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                            </span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="text-right col-lg-3 col-md-2 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                            <input class="fullWidth" type="text" id="addFromTime" name="addFromTime" placeholder="24 Hr">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
```

Comment: Hi, I have removed all other css and it is still behaving as described.